# Getting a java.util.NoSuchElementException even though I call .next() once

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Even though I have called Iterator.next() I'm still having the nosuchelementexception.

```
ListIterator<BankAccount_4> userDataIterator = userData.listIterator();
                        while (userData.iterator().hasNext()){
                            BankAccount_4 bankAccount4 = userDataIterator.next();
                           if (bankAccount4.getAccountNum()!=bankAccount_4.getAccountNum()) {
                               userDataIterator.add(bankAccount_4);
                               String fileName = bankAccount4.getAccountNum() + " - " + bankAccount4.getCustomerAccName() + "'s Account details";
                               dataPersistency(displayAccount(bankAccount4) + "\n\n" + computeInterest(bankAccount4), fileName);
                           }
                       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second line ( `while (userData.iterator().hasNext()){` ) appears to be retrieving a new iterator every time. The new iterator is probably not at the same place as the existing one, so you're always asking whether there's an element after the start (in a really inefficient way). I suspect what's happening is that you're iterating clear off the end of the list, because the `while` condition is always true.

Why aren't you just querying the iterator you already have ( `userDataIterator.hasNext()` )? Even better, why not just use a [Java for-each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) and skip explicitly messing with iterators at all? It's basically syntactic sugar for what you're doing, but more concisely and without the risk of screwing it up.